# How do I say that a number is a lot, "alta", "larĝa" or "granda" nombro?

Tags: word-choice

For example, how do I translate the following sentence?

> 2,302 is a very high number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A search in [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com) for `\bgrandan? nombr` (*granda nombr* with or without accusative) gives 85 results while `\baltan? nombr` only has 4. So I would say that both are valid but *granda nombro* is much more common.

*larĝa nombro* doesn't have any results, which I think is to be expected because it would be like saying "a wide number" which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Admittedly, the phrase *larĝa nombro* is funny and vivid.

Answer (score 5):

I reckon the word *granda* is the best choice. In [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#nombro) I found the following example sentence:

> ĉu vi sciis, kiel **granda** estos la nombro de viaj tagoj?

(Emphasis is mine.)

Thus when speaking of numbers, you speak of *grandeco*. This is however mentioned under the definition of *quantity*, not actual numbers. But it seems logical that the same word be used to express the greatness.